# Issue in File path

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project there is a folder and in that folder there is text file. I want to read that text file

```
        string FORM_Path = @"C:\Users\...\Desktop\FormData\Login.txt";
        bool first = true;
        string line;
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(FORM_Path))
            {
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
             }
          }
```

but I always get an error - file does not exist. how can i solve the problem in the path of text file.

Comment: relative path is not valid. You should give full path to the file you want to read

Comment: is your folder at the same level as the application?

Comment: ya......i use hardcoded path also still the same problem

Comment: I hope "..." is actually replaced by the user profile and that you have access to that user profile (unless its your own).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file's properties are set to copy the file to output directory. Then you can use the following line to get full path of your text file:

```
string FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "FormData\Login.txt");
```

Comment: but name Application does not exist in my context

Comment: add `using System.Windows.Forms` at the top of your code or simply replace `Application` with `System.Windows.Forms.Application` in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to give relative path instead of physical path. If you can use asp.net use Server.MapPath

```
string FORM_Path = Server.MapPath("~/FormData/Login.txt");
```

If the text file is in execution folder then you can use [AppDomain.BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string FORM_Path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "FormData\\Login.txt";
```

If it is not possible to use some base path then you can give complete path.

Comment: but i have an error name Server doed not exist in the current context

Comment: And this is a windows application

Answer (score 0):

You path is not in correct format. Use `@".\FormData\Login.txt"` instead of what you have

Comment: Open Command Prompt and invoke dir "your path". Your file should be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using relative paths. Instead consider using the methods in the [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

1. [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)
2. [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Step 1: get absolute path of the executable

```
var path = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
```

Step 2: get the working dir

```
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Step 3: build the new path

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(dir , @"FormData\Login.txt");
```